# objcopy: fails to copy a particular section (`.rodata' required but not present [...])

Tags: c, objcopy

I compiled a Hello World C file and need just one section (only the hello world function) of it.

The compiled file has the format elf32-i386 and contains 4 sections: `.rodata`, `.text.hello`, `.comment`, `.eh_frame`.

I tried to use objcopy to extract only the `.text.hello` section: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/01/objcopy-examples/ example 3.

It fails, reporting:

```
BFD: hello_new: symbol `.rodata' required but not present
objcopy:hello_new: No symbols
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you mentioned you need only the the `.text` section - for the purpose of runtime execution?   That is not right:   if that hello functions has strings hardcoded inside, all these strings will be located inside `.rodata` section, so are u going to ignore this section?

`.eh_frame` is for debugger, and `.comment` i think is not needed, but `.data` is also needed.

Another thing is the relocation table - if the fucntion is to be dynamically loaded into some arbitrary memory region, then lots of area INSIDE the function may need to be patched.....check `objdump -r` of your ELF to find out if there is any relocation entries.   if not, u are safe.

Also, anything inside your function declared as "const" will also go into the `.rodata` section - global data of course.   Variables or constants local to the function are on the stack.   And all global data are located inside `.data` section.

But coming back to the original error, the reason is because the example 3 in the original URL does not have cross-referencing (the `.interp` section) and therefore `objdump -s` will not have error.   Your case, `.text` does have cross-referencing to `.rodata` section, but is not available after you have extracted just the `.text` section out.