# Remove unused section using objcopy

Tags: gcc, ld, objcopy

Suppose I have the following source file:

```
// file.c:
void f() {}
void g() {}
```

I compile it into object file using `gcc -ffunction-sections`:

```
$ gcc -c -ffunction-sections file.c -o file.o
# It now has at least two sections: `.text.f' (with `f'), `.text.g' (with `g').
```

Then I try to remove section `.text.g` (with `g`) from object file:

```
$ objcopy --remove-section .text.g file.o
objcopy: stQOLAU8: symbol `.text.g' required but not present
objcopy:stQOLAU8: No symbols
```

So, **is there way to remove function-specific section from object file** (compiled with `-ffunction-sections`)?

Extra info:

1. Full list of symbols in `file.o` is:

   ```
   $ objdump -t file.o 

   file.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

   SYMBOL TABLE:
   0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 file.c
   0000000000000000 l    d  .text  0000000000000000 .text
   0000000000000000 l    d  .data  0000000000000000 .data
   0000000000000000 l    d  .bss   0000000000000000 .bss
   0000000000000000 l    d  .text.f        0000000000000000 .text.f
   0000000000000000 l    d  .text.g        0000000000000000 .text.g
   0000000000000000 l    d  .note.GNU-stack        0000000000000000 .note.GNU-stack
   0000000000000000 l    d  .eh_frame      0000000000000000 .eh_frame
   0000000000000000 l    d  .comment       0000000000000000 .comment
   0000000000000000 g     F .text.f        0000000000000007 f
   0000000000000000 g     F .text.g        0000000000000007 g
   ```
2. My goal is to eliminate some sections from object file similarly to what `ld --gc-sections` does.

Or is there some theoretical reason why such task is absolutely out of the scope of `objcopy` and can only be performed with `ld -r`?

Comment: Have you tried reporting this to [Bintools tracker](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/)?

Comment: @yugr, no, IIRC, I didn't. Do you think it's really a bug and should be reported?

Comment: I'd report it, `objcopy` behavior does not make sense (if you do, send them the `.s`, not the `.c`).

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25216482/2170527) claims that `.text.FOO` can't be removed as it's referenced from some other section. Sounds too vague for me though.

Comment: @yugr, I submitted: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=24031.

Comment: @yugr, [got answer](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=24031#c1):  "There is a relocation for `.eh_frame` that references `.text.g`".

Comment: Tried asking Andreas whether there's a workaround.

Comment: @yugr, doesn't `ld --gc-sections` act as partial workaround?

Comment: It's not a workaround but rather a main flag to use with `-ffunction-sections`. But `objcopy` gives full control over what gets into final executable so it's unusability is depressing.