# Remove section created with __attribute__((section))

Tags: c, elf, objcopy

I have a number of functions and corresponding unit tests. I would like to embed the tests into the codebase itself. I came up with the following solution:

```
void a() {
  // this code should be tested
}

__attribute__((section(".tests")))
void a_test() {
  // test if a() works
}
```

The tests are placed in a the section `.tests` which I can strip for release builds. I tried the following:

```
$ gcc -c a.c -o a.orig.o # a.c is shown above
$ objcopy -R.tests a.orig.o a.o
objcopy: a.o: symbol `.tests' required but not present
objcopy:a.o: no symbols
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24234001/8746648) which describes a similar problem where the answering said that it's because the section is being cross referenced from somewhere.

I think `.eh_frame` is that guilty section, since removing it will 
work:

```
$ objcopy -R.tests -R.eh_frame a.orig.o a.o
```

- Can I remove this section without consequences?
- Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discard the section in a linker script. Example:

```
SECTIONS {
  /DISCARD/ : { *(.tests) }
}
```